# Nodejs crypto md5 hash gives me digest of size 24 bytes, instead of expected 16

Tags: node.js, encryption, hash, cryptography, md5

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var key1 = crypto.createHash('md5').update('abcdefgh').digest();
var key2 = crypto.createHash('md5').update('abcdefgh').digest('base64');
var key3 = crypto.createHash('md5').update('abcdefgh').digest('hex');
var key4 = crypto.createHash('md5').update('abcdefgh').digest('latin1');
console.log('Key sizes :', key1.toString().length, key2.toString().length, key3.toString().length, key4.toString().length ); 
//Key sizes : 16 24 32 16
```

Doesn't md5 supposed to return 16 byte digest always?

Comment: The output does not look like MD5 output, it does not look random, 0xc2 occurs 7 times Perhaps it is the console.log that is causing the unexpected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[hash.digest(*encoding*) docs](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_hash_digest_encoding)**

> Calculates the digest of all of the data passed to be hashed (using the hash.update() method). The encoding can be `'hex'`, `'latin1'` or `'base64'`. If encoding is provided a string will be returned; otherwise a Buffer is returned.

`'binary'` is not a recognized type of encoding for `digest`. By default an encoding of type `'buffer'` is used.

Instead, use `'hex'` or `'base64'`

```
var key1 = crypto.createHash('md5').update('abcdefgh').digest('hex');

key1.length
// => 16

key1.toString()
// => 'e8dc4081b13434b45189a720b77b6818'
```

Note the output is 32 chars, where each 2 chars represents a single byte in hex format.

So the hash size is actually (32/2=16) **16 bytes**.

---

> `binary` output is self explanatory, no encoding

Well no, it's not self-explanatory. It's an undocumented parameter value. But, notice tho that `encoding` is an *optional* parameter.

If you don't use an argument when calling `digest`, you still get a 16-byte result

```
var key1 = crypto.createHash('md5').update('abcdefgh').digest()

key1.length
// => 16

key1.toString()
// => '��@��44�Q�� �{h\u0018'

key1.toString().length
// => 16
```

Note that when the `'buffer'` type is used, the default encoding for a `Buffer` is `'utf8'`. So when we call `buffer.toString` we get this nasty output. Do you see the `\u` in there? That's unicode. You can easily convert the buffer to a `hex` string (or `base64`) if you didn't use the proper `digest` argument, tho

```
// digest defaults to 'buffer' for unrecognized type
var key1 = crypto.createHash('md5').update('abcdefgh').digest('')

key1.length
// => 16

key1.toString()
// => '��@��44�Q�� �{h\u0018'

key1.toString('hex')
// => 'e8dc4081b13434b45189a720b77b6818'
```

The resulting bytes in the buffer are the same regardless of the argument passed to digest. The encoding is just passed along to the buffer, which can be changed whenever you choose to convert the buffer to a string.

Comment: `binary` output is self explanatory, no encoding.

Comment: `'binary'` and `''` encoding methods are treated as equal. Your down-vote is invalid.

Comment: Time to learn what an encoding is, binary just is, no meaning the the bytes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @naomik , updated my question. Please ignore Buffer, i used that just for debugging.

Comment: @Prabhat what is your question now? I just told you that the length of a string-representation of your 16-byte buffer doesn't change the fact that the buffer length is 16. The 'hex' string of your buffer is 32 chars long, but it represents 16 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

The Buffer constructor (which has been deprecated), expects a second argument for the encoding. If you don't specify one, it interprets the input as UTF-8.

Your md5 hash is not valid UTF-8, but the Buffer constructor attempts to construct a valid UTF-8 string from it. In my opinion, it should substitute [replacement characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character) for the invalid bytes, but what it seems to end up doing is the following: For each of your bytes that have a `0` as the first bit, nothing is changed (they are already valid), for each byte that has a `1` as the first bit, it encodes the byte as the following two bytes:

```
110000xx 10xxxxxx
```

Where the `x`s are the bits of the byte it is encoding. That happens eight times in your case, which always results in a `c2` or `c3` followed by another byte. All the bytes that have a `0` in the first position are encoded normally. You end up with eight extra bytes, and `16 + 8 = 24`:

You should specify that you want the buffer to accept binary:

```
console.log(new Buffer(key1, 'binary'));
```

and, since the Buffer constructor is deprecated, you should switch to [Buffer.from](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_string_encoding):

```
console.log(Buffer.from(key1, 'binary'));
```